# Sitecore user manager showing wrong timestamp

Tags: timestamp, sitecore, sitecore6, usermanager

I have been having a weird issue on a Sitecore site using Sitecore.NET 6.6.0 (rev. 140410) and it happens only on the production server!

When you open *Security* -> *User Manager*, select a user and then click *Edit*, the Information tab shows all time-stamps (except created) as current date time! See screenshot below:

[image: User manager time-stamp issue]

This however works fine on our development server which uses same Sitecore version. I must add this is for an intranet site & hence does have access restrictions on production.

Any ideas what might be going wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you are checking this class 
`Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Security.EditUser.EditUserPage` you will find the code related to `lastLogindate`, `creatiodate`, etc:

```cs
 MembershipUser user2 = Membership.GetUser(user.Name);
 if (user2 != null)
 {
    CultureInfo culture = User.Current.Profile.Culture;
    this.LastLoginDate.Text = FormatDate(user2.LastLoginDate, culture);
    this.CreationDate.Text = FormatDate(user2.CreationDate, culture);
    this.LastActivityDate.Text = FormatDate(user2.LastActivityDate, culture);
    this.LastPasswordChangedDate.Text = FormatDate(user2.LastPasswordChangedDate, culture);
    this.LastLockoutDate.Text = FormatDate(user2.LastLockoutDate, culture);
 }
```

Looks like Membership database is using UTC time that the difference between your time. 
   Please check this [article](http://forums.asp.net/t/1617498.aspx?Membership%20LastLoginDate%20has%20incorrect%20time).

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, the time stamp displayed is always just the current date time and not a different date time. So if I close user manager & open again, it once again updates to show current date time! Which is what I don't get.

Comment: Can you check if somebody modify this file: \Website\sitecore\shell\Applications\Security\EditUser\EditUser.xaml.xml

Comment: Thanks heaps for trying to help. Looks like regular Sitecore users do have time-stamp displayed correctly. It is only those Sitecore users that use domain controllers that are having this issue. So this could be because they are probably constantly polled in background & Sitecore is not suited to handle this.